# React Native Development Server closed automatically after successful build

Tags: react-native

I am new to ReactNative. I have installed react-native in my Ubuntu(18.04). I am trying to run the basic app after installation using CLI.

I am trying to make the build in android using sudo react-native run-android after successful build server closed automatically. It means that I have to run the command every time after making change.

Development Server closed automatically.

Please find the screenshot.

[Development Server Closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxJlG.png)

Answer (score 1):

This error is coming because some process is already running on 8081 port. Stop that process and then run your command, it will run your code. For this first list all the process which are using this port by typing

```
$ adb reconnect
```

This is not necessary in most cases, but just in case, let's reset your connection with your mobile and restart adb server. Finally:

```
$ adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Then run this command

```
lsof -i :8081
```

You will get a Process id which is using port 8081 Now kill the process

```
$ sudo kill -9 <PID>
```

Then run the project
`react-native run-android`

Comment: Still getting the same problem after running the above commands.
Also, I tried to find out the PID using sudo lsof -i tcp:8081. But, there was none. So, I run the command react-native run-android. But the same problem.

Comment: Try to run in another port like 3131. Run the command:react-native run-android --port=3131

Comment: please try: react-native start

Comment: I tried npm start, react-native start but react-native run-android command is always closed after first successful run.

Comment: run react-native start and reload the app from emulator

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issues.
I solved the issues by changing node version from 13.3.0 to node version 10.18.0.